# Uninstalling Exchange 2010: Cannot find MSI for Microsoft Exchange 2007 Enterprise Anti-spam Signatures (ASEntSig.MSI)

Tags: exchange-2010, uninstall

Finished migrating from Microsoft Exchange 2010 to Microsoft Exchange 2016 and I am decommissioning the Exchange 2010 server.

When uninstalling Exchange 2010 I am getting an error, the uninstaller is looking for `ASEntSig.MSI` for `Microsoft Exchange 2007 Enterprise Anti-spam Signatures` and it cannot find it.

In the directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\TransportRoles\agents\Hygiene` there is a `ASEntSig.MSI` file but it doesn't seem to want to work.

How can I proceed or where can I download the appropriate MSI?

[image: windows installer]

[image: exchange 2010 uninstall progress]

[image: directory]

Comment: `there is a ASEntSig.MSI file but it doesn't seem to want to work.` The original media or what ever the most recent media used (service pack) may work. That applies to any Windows Installer managed product. Otherwise you may want to try the hack here: https://anishjohnes.wordpress.com/2019/11/

Comment: @GregAskew that did the trick! I used the trick provided on that blog and it fixed the issue. Exchange 2010 is now uninstalled. Thanks for the quick response, much appreciated!